# Jenkins/Hudson CLI API to modify the node labels using Groovy

Tags: java, groovy, hudson, jenkins

Does anyone know how to modify the Jenkins/Hudson node labels in a non-manually way? I mean, thorough an API like the CLI API that this tool offers (without restarting Jenkins/Hudson of course).

My guess is that the best option is using a Groovy script to enter into the Jenkins/Hudson guts. Executing something like:

java -jar -s HUDSON_URL:8080 groovy /path/to/groovy.groovy

Being the content of that script something like:

```
for (aSlave in hudson.model.Hudson.instance.slaves) {
   labels = aSlave.getAssignedLabels()
   println labels
   **aSlave.setLabel("blabla")** // this method doesn't exist, is there any other way???
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Victor

Answer (score 10):

Note: the other answers are a bit old, so it could be that the API has appeared since then.

Node labels are accessed in the API as a single string, just like in the Configure screen.

To read and write labels: [Node.getLabelString()](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Slave.html#getLabelString%28%29) and [Node.setLabelString(String)](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Node.html#setLabelString(java.lang.String)).

Note that you can get the effective labels as well via: [Node.getAssignedLabels()](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Node.html#getAssignedLabels()), which returns a Collection of LabelAtom that includes dynamically computed labels such as the 'self-label' (representing the node name itself).

Last, these methods on the [Node](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Node.html) class are directly accessible from the slave objects also, e.g. as a System Groovy Script:

```
hudson = hudson.model.Hudson.instance
hudson.slaves.findAll { it.nodeName.equals("slave4") }.each { slave -> 
  print "Slave  $slave.nodeName : Labels: $slave.labelString"
  slave.labelString = slave.labelString + " " + "offline"
  println "   --> New labels: $slave.labelString"
}
hudson.save()
```

Comment: How and where would I run this script? Also it appears there is an extra } at the end.

Comment: It doesn't appear as if these changes persist, though.

Comment: I didn't realize that, but you are correct. Did you find a way (an API) for doing that by any chance ?

Comment: `hudson.model.Hudson.instance.save()`

Comment: I don't know Groovy but this snippet still definitely seems wrong - has unmatched `}` and doesn't run in Jenkins.

Comment: Indeed, the brace was aloof, I removed it and that should resolve the issue you're having. Thanks!

Comment: This script is still buggy: It modifies the labels of _all_ slaves instead of using only `slave4`.

Comment: Hmm, you're right @hagello ! I rewrote the snippet to make the change only on slave4.

Answer (score 2):

I've found a way to do this using the Groovy Postbuild Plugin.

I have a Jenkins job that takes a few parameters (NodeToUpdate, LabelName, DesiredState) and executes this content in the Groovy Postbuild Plugin:

```
nodeName = manager.envVars['NodeToUpdate']
labelName = manager.envVars['LabelName']
set = manager.envVars['DesiredState']

for (node in jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.nodes) {
    if (node.getNodeName().equals(nodeName)) {
        manager.listener.logger.println("Found node to update: " + nodeName)
        oldLabelString = node.getLabelString()
        if (set.equals('true')) {
            if (!oldLabelString.contains(labelName)) {
                manager.listener.logger.println("Adding label '" + labelName     + "' from node " + nodeName);
                newLabelString = oldLabelString + " " + labelName
                node.setLabelString(newLabelString)
                node.save()
            } else {
                manager.listener.logger.println("Label '" + labelName + "' already exists on node " + nodeName)
            }
        }
        else {
            if (oldLabelString.contains(labelName)) {
                manager.listener.logger.println("Removing label '" + labelName + "' from node " + nodeName)
                newLabelString = oldLabelString.replaceAll(labelName, "")
                node.setLabelString(newLabelString)
                node.save()
            } else {
                manager.listener.logger.println("Label '" + labelName + "' doesn't exist on node " + nodeName)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! help me a lot!! perfectly without error.

Answer (score 1):

I've not seen a way yet to change the slave label either.

I've taken to editing the main config.xml file and issuing a reload from the CLI.

This has it's own problems though - any jobs currently running are lost until the next jenkins restart - see https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-3265