# Groovy script for modifying Jenkins nodes labels

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-agent

I have Jenkins with few agent nodes (Slave1, Slave2 & Slave3).
Each agent has a few labels associated with it, i.e Slave1 (test build python), Slave2 (develop update clean)...

I'm looking for groovy script that I can run from Jenkins Script Console to modify labels on given agents at once by adding/removing "-offline" suffix for each label on each agent, i.e Slave1 will have (test-offline build-offline python-offline) & Slave2 (develop-offline update-offline clean-offline).

I need this functionality in order to prevent next job start running on these agents (let's say I want to set them offline for maintenance, once all jobs finished on these nodes). And once I done with maintenance on these agents, I need to run another groovy script which set back all labels as they was configured before, i.e Slave1 (test build python), Slave2 (develop update clean).

So far I've found old [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8823443/jenkins-hudson-cli-api-to-modify-the-node-labels-using-groovy) about similar issue. The bellow code can return all labels for chosen agent, but it's adding "offline" as additional label and not as a suffix for each existing label:

```
hudson = hudson.model.Hudson.instance
hudson.slaves.findAll { it.nodeName.equals("slave1") }.each { slave -> 
  print "Slave  $slave.nodeName : Labels: $slave.labelString"
  slave.labelString = slave.labelString + " " + "offline"
  println "   --> New labels: $slave.labelString"
}
hudson.save()
```

So I have few questions:

1. How to use list of nodes (slave1,slave2, slave3...) and not single node slave1
2. How to add/remove"-offline" suffix to/from labels? It can be two different script for adding and removing labels suffix.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some issue in the script.

```
hudson = hudson.model.Hudson.instance 
hudson.slaves.findAll { it.nodeName.equals("slave1") }.each { slave ->    
    print "Slave  $slave.nodeName : Labels: $slave.labelString"
    labels = aSlave.getLabelString()
    labels = labels + "-offline"
    aSlave.setLabelString(labels)
    println "   --> New labels: $slave.labelString" 
} 
hudson.save()
```

Here too the assumption is that there is only one lable. Then only this will work.

if there are multiple labels

```
labels = aSlave.getLabelString()
labelList = labels.split(' ') //This is a list
labelList[0] = labelList[0]+"-offline"
labels = labelList.join(' ')
```

You will have to split the labelString by space and then work on them.

And to get all slaves you can create a loop as follows

```
for (aSlave in hudson.model.Hudson.instance.slaves) {
    if(aSlave.name == "")//here you can pass a list or a single node for which changes needs to be done
    println "${aSlave.name}"
}
```

I would do something like this for multiple nodes

```
hudson = hudson.model.Hudson.instance 
for (aSlave in hudson.slaves) {
   labels = aSlave.getLabelString()
   labelList = labels.split(' ') //This is a list
   i = 0
   for (individualLabel in labelList) {
       if(individualLabel == "python") {
            labelList[i] = labelList[i]+"-offline"
       }
       i++
   }
   labels = labelList.join(' ')
   aSlave.setLabelString(labels)
 }
 hudson.save()
```

You can also add a condition on name of the slave if this has to be done for a particular slave.

let me know if this works

Comment: Thank you for the answer!! But using only one labels also not working... It still add additional label"-offline" and not append "-offline" as suffix to existing label (test-offline"). Could you please give an example how I can "split the labelString by space and then work on them"? In additional I don't need to work on all slaves, my goal to provide only these slaves that I need

Comment: I have updated the answer. Have tried it at my end. see if this helps

Comment: Now your first script return following error: "No such property: aSlave for class: Script1". I've corrected it by adding this line: for (aSlave in hudson.model.Hudson.instance.slaves)" And now it's working for single label! Thanks! Now I'll try make it work for multiple labels.

Comment: There must be a loop somewhere. Can you paste your code here.

Comment: I've put working & not working codes in my original question post, please take a look

Comment: Have tried to fix what you did. Though It might not be exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

So far, thanks to @pratikvasa, for single node with single label working code is:

```
hudson = hudson.model.Hudson.instance
hudson.slaves.findAll { it.nodeName.equals("slave1") }.each { slave -> 
  println "   --> Slave  $slave.nodeName : Labels: $slave.labelString"
  slave.labelString = slave.labelString + "-offline"
  println "   --> New labels: $slave.labelString"
}
hudson.save()
```

And for single node & multiple labels working code is:

```
hudson = hudson.model.Hudson.instance
hudson.slaves.findAll { it.nodeName.equals("slave1") }.each { slave -> 
  println "   --> Slave  $slave.nodeName : Current Labels: $slave.labelString"
  labels = slave.labelString

def list = ["$labels"]
  labelList = labels.split(' ')
  i = 0
  for (item in labelList) {
  print "   --> $i Label In The List: "
  println item
  labelList[i] = labelList[i] + "-offline"
  i++
  }

  labels = labelList.join(' ')

  slave.labelString = labels

  print "   --> New Labels Are: $slave.labelString"
}
```

Using `+ "-offline"` will append suffix to each label & using `- "-offline"` will remove suffix from each label.

Comment: I can't figure out how to answer question #1: How to use list of nodes (slave1,slave2, slave3...) and not single node slave1?

Comment: can you explain this more in detail. In your code **it.nodeName.equals("slave1") ** this would select only one node. Remove that to get the list of all slaves

Comment: This is a point, I don't need all slaves... I want to provide list of slaves that I need to work on

Comment: ya..that is simple..you can store the name of the nodes in a list for which you want to perform the actifity. And then in the above code just add a condition yourList.contains(it.nodeName) and then perform the activity

Answer (score 0):

This is simply worked for me, you have to provide in script approval for the first time

`Jenkins.instance.getNode("${env.NODE_NAME}").setLabelString("mylabel") Jenkins.instance.save()`